# View old command output from a closed terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, logging, mercurial, rhel-5

I ran

```
hg pull
hg up
```

to check in my working copy to the Mercurial repository.

I got some warning messages in the terminal. I closed the terminal and now I want to see  those messages again.

Are they stored somewhere? I use Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.

Comment: Since you are using version control you can always view what exact changes you did to the files, at least, and restore them if it's needed. Also, `hg pull; hg update` - that _pulls_ from a remote repository and _updates_ the local one to the remote state; it does not check in your working copy (`commit` and `push` would do this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be depending on the terminal emulation you are running, and the log settings you are using.

By default, all terminal emulations I know discard logged output once they are closed.

So, unless you enabled persistent logging *beforehand* (in which case you would also know where the logging is done *to*), the output is lost.

Comment: I'm a Linux user and there I agree completely — but I just learned that the Terminal app in Mac OS will save the scrollback buffer when you quit it.

Comment: @MartinGeisler: See? "All terminal emulations I know." :-D  But thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4):

nope, it is not usual to store the output of every program you run. you could activate some paranoid logging and spam your disc, but that is not the usual behavior.

so, for your case right now: nope.